# SpEL language - auto null reference initalization

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Please look at example code:

```
public static class MyTestClass {
    public List<Boolean> booleans = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpelParserConfiguration config = new SpelParserConfiguration(true, true);

    MyTestClass myTestClass = new MyTestClass();

    SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(config);
    Object value = parser.parseExpression("booleans[1]").getValue(myTestClass); //exception
```

I try to initalize boolean list with default values. The problem is, Boolean class does not have default constructor so I got exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Boolean.<init>()
```

**It is possible to write how new objects should be initalized if they dont exists in list?**

Comment: *"I try to initalize boolean list with default values"* Where do you try that? --- Did you try e.g. `public List<Boolean> booleans = Arrays.asList(true, false, false, true);` for a list of size 4?

Comment: @Andreas fixed 'simple' 
I try to intalize it automatically by SpEL expressions instead of manually while list creation

Comment: Since your question is about the initialization, it would be good to actually see *how* you're (trying) to do that initialization, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry that the auto-grow collection features in `SpEL` only works if the item has the default constructor.

Unless you have a strong reason the need to initialise a list using `SpEL` , I suggest you use the normal java method call , it is much faster than `SpEL` and also type safely.

If you insist doing it in `SpEL` , the best you can do is :

```
List<Boolean> result =  parser.parseExpression( "{true,true,false,false,true}").getValue(List.class);
myTestClass.booleans = result;
```